# Is there a way to monitor Newly created Index Component Sync Sp2013 search

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, index

I am in a process of fixing degraded Index Component in my search topology. I was able to remove and new index component. After i added index component now its stuck at status degraded, i know it takes some time before it comes online, but do we have any too to track the sync progress of that newly created index component.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You should see it with:

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus -SearchApplication $ssa -Text
```

Maybe narrow it down to the index component:

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication | Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus -HealthReport -Component IndexComponent1 -Text
```